# Creating and sending custom events

Tags: java, events, event-handling

How can I send custom events from one object to another?
I have 2 Working objects of same type, main class uses worker. 
if some condition is true in worker1 it should send ea event to the main class that will switch the workers.

This is my scenario:

```
class Worker1 extends Base{
   public void DoSomeWork(Arg argument){
      if(someCondition=true){
          SendEvent();
      }
   }
}

class MainClassThatUsesWorker{
    Base worker = new Worker1();

    public void EventArrived(){
        worker = new Worker2();      
    }

    public void UseWorKer(){
        worker.DoSomeWork();      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you implement the [observer pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-05/04-qa-0525-observer.html). Your main class is then the observer and the worker is the observable (or subject). When the worker fires the appropriate event, your main class handles it appropriately. Be careful with the synchronization because you work with multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at how Swing etc. do it. Basically you define an event class and a Listener interface which is implemented by the main class (or some other handler) . Then you register the event with the senders, i.e. put them into some collection and when the event is fired you iterate through that collection and invoke the handling method on the listeners.

Something like this (simplified):

```
class MyEvent { ... };

interface MyListener {
  void handleEvent( MyEvent e );
}

//inside the worker class
public void SendEvent() {
  MyEvent e = new MyEvent();
  for( MyListener l : listeners ) {
    l.handleEvent( e );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please respect the Java naming conventions. Methods should start with a lower-case letter.

If you want the main object to be notified when something happens in the worker, the worker must have a reference to the main object:

```
public void doSomeWork(MainClassThatUsesWorker main) {
    if (someCondition) {
        main.eventArrived();
    }
}
```

You might also want to accept other kinds of listeners then just the `MainClassThatUsesWorker`. In this case, declare a `WorkerListener` interface having a `eventArrived` method, and take a `WorkerListener` as argument. The `MainClassThatUsesWorker` will have to implement this interface to listen to events triggered by the worker, but other classes may also implement the same interface and be passed as argument.